# XSL mapping, making a hashmap

Tags: xml, xslt, dictionary, mapping

I need a little help with making an xsl map file.
I have an input. This containsa a list of some items:

```
<root>
    <resultListIn>
        <resultItemIn>
            <a>aaa</a>
            <b>bbb</b>
            <c>ccc1</c>
        </resultItemIn>
        <resultItemIn>
            <a>aaa</a>
            <b>bbb</b>
            <c>ccc2</c>
        </resultItemIn>
        <resultItemIn>
            <a>aab</a>
            <b>bbb</b>
            <c>ccc3</c>
        </resultItemIn>
        <resultItemIn>
            <a>aaa</a>
            <b>bbc</b>
            <c>ccc4</c>
        </resultItemIn>
        <resultItemIn>
            <a>aaa</a>
            <b>bbc</b>
            <c>ccc5</c>
        </resultItemIn>
    </resultListIn>
</root>
```

Now i would like to transform it into a structure that looks like a map: our „key” will be the the < a> and < b> elements (from each resultItem), and the value will be a list of < c> elements from the every < resultItem> that has the same < a> and < b> values.

So the output should look like (you can see the "cc1"+"cc2" and "cc4"+"cc5" values in the proper resultItem's < cItemList>, because in the input the < a> and < b> elements were the same in the corresponding < resultItem>):

```
<resultroot>
    <resultListOut>
        <resultItem>
            <a>aaa</a>
            <b>bbb</b>
            <cItemList>
                <c>cc1</c>
                <c>cc2</c>
            </cItemList>
        </resultItem>
        <resultItem>
            <a>aab</a>
            <b>bbb</b>
            <cItemList>
                <c>cc3</c>
            </cItemList>
        </resultItem>
        <resultItem>
            <a>aaa</a>
            <b>bbc</b>
            <cItemList>
                <c>cc4</c>
                <c>cc5</c>
            </cItemList>
        </resultItem>
    </resultListOut>
</resultroot>
```

Can you guys help me with this? I don’t need a whole xsl code, only some guidance, advice on how to where to start, what kind of algorithm should i write. I don’t really see how to implement this in xsl (and sadly i can’t use Java).

I tried to think through it with for-each structures but it's a big mess as i see it.

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. Do a search -  it's one of the most often asked questions here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: To expand on that, search for "Muenchian grouping" if you are using XSLT 1.0, or xsl:for-each-group if using 2.0. The 2.0 solution will be much easier. You might try to get it working with a simple key (one element only) before attempting to extend it to a composite key.

Comment: Thank you guys for both of you. Keyword "grouping" was the key for me. Using that i found muenchian grouping as well (along with a lot of examples). 
michael.hor257  please answer the question, i'd give you the points :)

Michael Kay: i needed the composite key, because in my real schema the elements "a" and "b" are "postcode" and "town", and i need both for identification, but thanks for the point!

Comment: Aren't postcodes unique by themselves?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Not necessarily. I grew up in a town that shared its zip code with two other towns.

Comment: Hi. No michael.hor, they aren't unique by themselves. Lots of our cities (Hungary) has more zip codes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have discovered, [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) is the answer if you're using XSLT 1.0.

To match on two elements, simply concatenate the two values (with a separator to prevent false positives), e.g.:

```
<xsl:key name="k" match="resultItem" use="concat(a,'|', b)"/>
```